# printing data from gridview

Tags: gridview

I have a gridview containing fields firstname, lastname and location. I have a print button and on clicking the print button, I want to print the each record's firstname, lastname and location on a already printed A4 sheet.

for example if i have 10 records, i need to print the details on 10 a4 sheets. any suggestions are much appreciated.

I am populating the values from database to datatable and the source it to the grid view.

i have this below code but it prints the entire gridview

```
function doPrint()
    {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');
        prtContent.border = 0; //set no border here
        var WinPrint = window.open('','','left=100,top=100,width=1000,height=1000,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,resizable=1');
        WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.outerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
    }
```

Comment: guys, is there any other way to achieve this?